# Angular, Bootstrap and Datepicker - forceParse does not conform to the given format

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am wondering how I can make forceParse to parse an inconsistent dateformat into a specific format, and not the default format.

A snippet :

```
model.dateOptions = {
  formatYear : 'yyyy',
  format : 'dd-MM-yyyy',
  forceParse : true
}
```